# Does UPDATE without WHERE clause lock a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, locking

Does the whole table `UPDATE` (without specifying `WHERE` clause) lock a table in PostgreSQL? E.g. does it prevents rows from being deleted / inserted?

E.g. if I run
`UPDATE t1 SET key = 'value'`
Can I expect no new rows will be inserted into `t1` during the `UPDATE` execution?

If no, can I expect `UPDATE` will update even the rows appeared after its start? (key has no `DEFAULT 'value'` in its definition)

Comment: If it was updating rows that where inserted after it started and there was a process that was continually inserting rows wouldn't that mean the update statement would never finish?

Comment: good point! Yes, it is barely possible `UPDATE` to be implemented in such manner to update newly inserted rows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An UPDATE without a WHERE clause will lock all rows in the table, but will not lock the table itself for DML.

The rows can not be deleted from a different transaction because they are locked.

But you can insert new rows without problems (assuming they do not violate any constraints).

Any row that is inserted *after* the UPDATE will not be seen by the UPDATE statement and thus they won't be changed.

Comment: @origaminal The doc in question is at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html , the last four are what you're calling 'table locks' -- although even permissive locks are still a form of table lock that will prevent attempts to take an exclusive lock.